# MVC2 validation without database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can we show MVC2 validation without database, just having the Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You just have to [add the Data Annotations](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) by hand to your Model. No database required.

Answer (score 0):

yes you do not need a database. here is an example of it

```
public class MyModel { 

     [Required]
     public int ID {get; set; }
     [StringLength(30)]
     public string Name {get; set; }
     public int Age {get; set; }

}
```

On you create or edit view which will be strogly typed to this class, the validation will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Data Annotations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs) in your model properties, such as:

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The model binder would then add the erros to the model if the field is empty or exceeds the maxlength.

Another option is for you to add your errors manually

```
public ActionResult method(MyModel model)
{
    if(model.AnswerToLifeUniverseAndAll!=42)
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError("Id_Of_The_Html_Elemet","Wrong Answer");
      return View(model);
```

this will get back to the view the user submitted, and will show the "Wrong Answer" error next to the field that has the provided Id.